# How to call pandas' DataFrame column, passed threw a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The DataFrame is:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({    'key':['II','I','I','III','II'],
                       'Z':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                       'd':[1,2,0,2,0],
                       'e':[0,2,0,3,0],
                       'f':[0,3,0,4,0],})
```

I have a function( it just encodes `features` in `data_aggregate`):

```
def Encode(data_aggregate, features):
    for feature in features:       
        l = len(data_aggregate)
        groups = data_aggregate.groupby(by=feature)
        groups_sizes = groups.size()
        for key in groups_sizes.keys():
            ratio = groups_sizes[key] / l
            data_aggregate.loc[data_aggregate.feature == key, [feature]] = ratio
    return data_aggregate
```

When i pass my `A` to `Encode`:

```
new = Encode(A, ['key'])
```

It returns an error:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-31-e896b315a285> in <module>()
    ----> 1 A.loc[A.feature == key, [feature]] = 111

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
       2742             if name in self._info_axis:
       2743                 return self[name]
    -> 2744             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
       2745 
       2746     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to re-invent `pd.factorize(A.key)` ?

Comment: @JonClements Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference a column with a variable name that contains a string using dot notation.

Try this instead

```
def Encode(data_aggregate, features):
    for feature in features:       
        l = len(data_aggregate)
        groups = data_aggregate.groupby(by=feature)
        groups_sizes = groups.size()
        for key in groups_sizes.keys():
            ratio = groups_sizes[key] / l
            data_aggregate.loc[data_aggregate[feature] == key, [feature]] = ratio
    return data_aggregate
```

***solution***
That said, you can do the same thing with

```
A.assign(key=A.key.map(A.key.value_counts(normalize=True)))

   Z  d  e  f  key
0  a  1  0  0  0.4
1  b  2  2  3  0.4
2  c  0  0  0  0.4
3  d  2  3  4  0.2
4  e  0  0  0  0.4
```

---

***functionalize***

```
def Encode(df, features):
    d = {k: df[k].map(df[k].value_counts(normalize=True)) for k in features}
    return df.assign(**d)
```

---

```
Encode(A, ['key'])

   Z  d  e  f  key
0  a  1  0  0  0.4
1  b  2  2  3  0.4
2  c  0  0  0  0.4
3  d  2  3  4  0.2
4  e  0  0  0  0.4
```

---

```
Encode(A, ['key', 'Z'])

     Z  d  e  f  key
0  0.2  1  0  0  0.4
1  0.2  2  2  3  0.4
2  0.2  0  0  0  0.4
3  0.2  2  3  4  0.2
4  0.2  0  0  0  0.4
```

Comment: v. nice - had forgotten about the `normalize` option.

Comment: Could you please explain, how this works :`df.assign(**d)`

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav observe how I called `assign` `A.assign(key=...`.  `assign` takes key/value pairs and assigns the values as new columns with header equal to the key.  `**dictionary` when used in context of passing to a function, will unpack the keys and values and pass them as key/value arguments to the functions.  But that is exactly, column names and column values in the dictionary named `d`.  So `df.assign(**d)` will assign new columns or overwrite existing ones with the keys and values in `d`.